# Couldn't upload photo in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I am using CodeIgniter framework for PHP.And I couldn't upload/update a photo.
Here is the edit-profile1.php **View**:

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();  ?>users/update/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="padd col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <label class="label">My IC/Matric Card</label></br>
            <input name="image"  placeholder="Upload" class="upload friendly"  type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" required>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 padd" style="overflow:auto;">
            <div class="picture"><img id="blah" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"  
            <?php
                if($userdata[0]['image'] == "")
                {
                    echo "src='https://style.anu.edu.au/_anu/4/images/placeholders/person.png'";
                }else{
                    echo "src='" . str_replace('/index.php/','/',base_url())."media/images/users/".$userdata[0]['image']."'";
                }
                ?> >
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <button type="submit" style='width: 100%; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom: 20px !important; background-color: #59d389; color: white;' class="btn btn-responsive  btn-md center-block">Save Changes</button>
                <input type="hidden"   value="<?php echo $userdata[0]['id']; ?>"  name="id" />
                <input type="hidden"   value="<?php echo $userdata[0]['account_status']; ?>"  name="id" />
                <input type="hidden"   value="<?php echo $userdata[0]['image']; ?>"  name="oldimage"/>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the Users.php **Controller**:

```
    public function profile()
    {
        $data['userdata'] = $this->usermodel->get_user($this->session->userdata('id'));
        $this->load->view('edit-profile1',$data);
    }
    public function update()
    {
        $user = new Users_model(); 
        // $user->phone1 = $this->input->post('phone1');
        $user->account_status = 1;
        //session data
        $user->id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $user->password = $this->session->userdata('password');
        $user->username = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $user->email = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $user->user_role = $this->session->userdata('user_role'); 
        //id to be set
        $id = $user->id; 

        if($_FILES['image'])
        {
            /* IMAGE UPLOADING START */
                $image_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
                $image_size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
                $image_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                $d=date('YmdHis');
                //$image_test_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $user->firstname.$user->lastname);
                $image_type = str_replace("image/", ".", $image_type);
                $image_name=$user->id . $image_type;
                $imgurl= str_replace("/index.php/","/",base_url())."media/images/users/".$image_name;   

                if($image_type==".jpeg" || $image_type==".png" || $image_type==".gif" )
                {   
                    $this->usermodel->upload_user_image($image_name);
                    $this->usermodel->update_image($user->id, $image_name);
                    $user->image = $image_name; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $user->image = $this->input->post('oldimage');
                }

            /* IMAGE UPLOADING END */
        }else{
            $user->image = $this->input->post('oldimage');
        }
        $res = $this->db->update('users', $user, array('id' => $id));
        $URL = base_url() . "users/profile/";
        redirect($URL, "refresh"); 
    }

}
```

And here is the Users_model.php **Model**:

```
public function upload_user_image($image_name) {

 $config['upload_path'] = 'media/images/users';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
 $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
 $config['file_name'] = $image_name;

 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 $this->upload->initialize($config);

 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
  $this->upload->display_errors('<span>', '</span>');
  $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
} else {
  $file_data = $this->upload->data();
  $data['success'] = "Your file is uploaded";
}


}
public function update_image($id,$image_name){

  $sql = "update users set image = '$image_name' where id = $id ";

  $this->db->query($sql);
 }
```

When the page redirect, the image is uploaded. The problem is, when refreshing manually, the placeholder image appear again and it means the photo wasn't updated to the database. 
Here is the link to the website: https://www.yiyalo.com
You can log in using these credentials 
id: qy_leong13@hotmail.com
pass: 123456

GO to My account > My profile to try it out

Comment: you misunderstood the process of image upload. You don't have to access ```$_FILE``` variable. Codeigniter having replacement for that. Whatever code you have written in model for user_image_upload, using that code only you can upload the image.

Comment: I don't understand what you said.

Comment: Have you got the answer?

Comment: @QiYang hello u der?

Comment: nope, it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload file in controller itself. If you are using file upload library then don't need to do it manually with `$_FILES` variable.

```
public function update()
{
    $user = new Users_model(); 
    // $user->phone1 = $this->input->post('phone1');
    $user->account_status = 1;
    //session data
    $user->id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $user->password = $this->session->userdata('password');
    $user->username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $user->email = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $user->user_role = $this->session->userdata('user_role'); 
    //id to be set
    $id = $user->id; 

    $config['upload_path'] = 'media/images/users';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    //$config['file_name'] = $image_name;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
        $this->upload->display_errors('<span>', '</span>');
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $data['success'] = "Your file is uploaded";
    }

    $res = $this->db->update('users', $user, array('id' => $id));
    $URL = base_url() . "users/profile/";
    redirect($URL, "refresh"); 
}
```

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: image_name

Filename: controllers/Users.php

Line Number: 48

Comment: What is your line number 48?? Can you notify which line is line 48?

Comment: $config['file_name'] = $image_name;

Comment: just remove that line, ```$config['file_name'] ``` this parameter used when you want to change the name of uploaded file before save it on disk.

Comment: what is the error? If any error then please paste it in question.